# Google Analytics - tracking somePage.exe pages

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

If I have my server setup to serve up pages with .exe extension as html content, and I put standard GA tracking code (javascript) onto my page, will GA reject hits to that page, since it's a .exe extension?

I am asking because .exe files are traditionally tracked as downloads by tracking tools...

...so has anybody had experience with putting GA on .exe files served up as web pages?

Answer (score 0):

If the .exe renders HTML and executes the GA tracking code, then it should appear in your Content Reports after the customary 24-48 hrs. Unsure if there are any restrictions for .exe files on the GA side (I would venture that there aren't any), but give it a try in a test profile and see what you get.

HTH,

KM

Comment: yeah...I don't think there should be a problem, but that darn wait time...was hoping someone knew offhand, but I guess will just have to try and see what happens :/